# PhpStorm ruby.exe: invalid option --no-cache (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, sass, phpstorm

I want to use file watcher for SCSS actions. But phpstorm is giving me this error.
`C:\Ruby22\bin\ruby.exe: invalid option --no-cache  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)`

Path was added while installing ruby. I checked the path and it was same as destination of ruby. I'm not find real solution about this issue. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: This is not an issue with the path, the error message clearly states you are trying to invoke ruby with an invalid option.

Comment: seems you have specified wrong program in your SCSS file watcher settings. It should not be a path to Ruby.exe, you need providing a path to scss.bat (must be smth like `C:\Ruby22\bin\scss.bat`)

Comment: @lena yes you were right, I noticed that. Then it was start working after change right path.

Answer (score 0):

You are running Compass with Sass command line options - thus the problem. When creating a watcher, please make sure to choose 'Compass SCSS', not 'SCSS'. Or, change your watcher settings accordingly, for example

```
Program: C:/Ruby193/bin/compass.bat
Arguments: compile
Working directory: $ProjectFileDir$
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/stylesheets
Settings above assume that you have your config.rb located in project root folder, and css_dir = "stylesheets"
```